# How do i get the key present in a hashmap by accessing the values present in it

Tags: c++17

I am trying to get the key of a given value using **C++**.

I have already tried `.find()` to get the value, but am unable to get it.

Are there other alternatives other than `find()`? Or Is there any inbuilt function to access a key without traversing it?

Comment: `find()` returns an iterator to the entry in the `Hash Table` dereferencing this iterator returns a reference to a **key**-**value** `pair`. Do you already have the key that you want to use [`find(const Key& key)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find)?

Comment: The `find()` method returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified string or character. You can achieve this by maintaining another hashmap, let's say `ReverseMap`, so whenever you put something in your original hashmap `<key>:<value>`, you also need to add its reverse `<value>:<key>` in `ReverseMap` as well. This way you can use `ReverseMap.find(value)` to get your desired value.